# Using Poltergeist, Phantom JS instances are not exiting during every rspec run

Tags: poltergeist

On every poltergeist test that is executed by rspec, if I create a new session using:

`Capybara.session_name="some_session_name"`

a phantomjs instance is started as a subprocess, and never quits until the test ends, causing an OOM on my build server.

I believe this is due to a failure to call driver.quit, as described in the [readme of Poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#memory-leak):

> If you run a few capybara sessions manually please make sure you've called session.driver.quit when you don't need session anymore. Forgetting about this causes memory leakage and your system's resources can be exhausted earlier than you may expect.

However, I call `page.driver.quit` in the `after` block of my tests.

Below is my after block code.  `$adhoc_sessions` is a global variable I populate every time I set `Capybara.session_name`, with the value matching the value set on `Capybara.session_name`.

```
config.after(:each) do
  if example.metadata[:js]

    $adhoc_sessions.each do |session_name|
      Capybara.using_session( session_name ) do
      page.driver.quit
      end
    end
    $adhoc_sessions.clear
  end
```

Any suggestions on what I could do better here? Am I failing to call some cleanup command?

Comment: After waiting a few days for here, I filed a bug as well.  Since I'm calling ```page.driver.quit```, AFAIK I'm doing the right thing.
https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/issues/419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that came from two constraints:

1. I don't think you can call **driver.quit** safely in Capybara without
   obtaining access to the private **@session_pool**, because Capybara has
   no  way to let users remove a session from a pool once it gets put
   in.  So, if you call driver.quit on a session, you can't remove that session
   from the pool, and eventually Capybara will try to **reset!** the session, causing
   Poltergeist to throw up an IOError because it's internal
   communication over websockets is not connected.
2. If you do instead
   whack the entire session pool after every test run, and quit every
   poltergeist driver within each session as you do so, eventually
   you'll run into a **TOO MANY OPEN FILES** error.  I.e.,:

*Method to recreate TOO MANY OPEN FILES error--do not use this!!*

```
# you have to do quite a few test runs to cause the open files error
config.append_after(:each) do
  session_pool = Capybara.instance_variable_get("@session_pool")
  session_pool.each do | key, value |
    value.driver.quit
  end
  session_pool.clear
end
```

I believe this to be a real poltergeist bug, but I don't care... and here's why... in running the above code, I noticed that creating a poltergeist session is a noticeably slow and resource intensive operation.   So, I've decided I'd rather have an  pool of sessions that never go away... the way Capybara appears to be designed.

The only problem with this approach becomes in using Capybara.session_name the way I do, which is to come up with arbitrary test names on a per test basis.  Maybe in one test I want each session_name to be the same as a user's database ID.  Or maybe I come up with 5 constants I use through out a test, and 5 different constants for a different test.    In other words, I may use 100s of session_name's in my test suite, but I only ever have a maximum of just a handful sessions for anyone given test.  So a good solution reuses poltergeist sessions, but let's me use arbitrary session name's per test run.

### This is my solution

*spec/utilities.rb*

```
# holds a single test's session name's, mapped to pooled session names
$capybara_session_mapper = {}

# called after each test,
# to make sure each test run has it's own map of session names
def reset_session_mapper
  $capybara_session_mapper.clear
end

# manages the mapped session name
def mapped_session_name(session_name)
  return :default if session_name == :default # special treatment for the built-in session
  $capybara_session_mapper[session_name] ||= $capybara_session_mapper.length
end

# in place of ever using Capybara.session_name directly, 
# this utility is used to handle the mapping of session names in a way across all tests runs
def in_client(name)  
  Capybara.session_name = mapped_session_name(session_name)

  yield
end
```

In *spec_helper.rb*:

```
config.after(:each) do
  Capybara.reset_sessions!
  reset_session_mapper
end
```

An example test that uses in_client instead of Capybara.session_name directly:

```
it "can't see a private thing until it is made public" do

  in_client(user1.id) do
    visit '/some/private/thing'
    expect(page).to have_selector('#private-notice')
  end

  in_client(user2.id) do
    visit '/expose/some/private/thing'
  end

  in_client(user1.id) do
    visit '/some/private/thing`
    expect(page).to have_selector('#private-content')
  end
end
```

[-- copied from my github answer](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/issues/419)